# CocoaLibSpotify not compatible with latest iOS hardware? Is there a solution?

Tags: ios, spotify

I was having some major issues linking the CocoaLibSpotify API to my project, about four to five hours of employer time, but I figured out it was because of the emulator I was targeting.

When set to a 64bit emulator, the project would give me a ton of errors, but when set to iPhone 3.5 inch the project would compile and run just fine. So I'm assuming it has to do with these new architectures. Is there a solution to this issue? I badly need this library and I'd prefer not to use the C library, but if there's no other choice I may have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 64bit is NOT mandatory.. you just can't COMPILE as arm64
It will work on any iOS hardware

---

it seems you want to compile for 64 -- not only run under 64 iOS

goto build settings > architectures and make sure you only use armv7s

Comment: well, it not THAT silly since apple wants us to add armv8 support. But you don't have to and _many_ libs aren't ready for it